# Only root route works in Sinatra with Passenger/Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, sinatra, passenger

I have a sinatra app running with Apache/Passenger in a subfolder with the following in an .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  Allow from all
  PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
  RackEnv development
  RackBaseURI /myapp
  PassengerAppRoot /home/username/myapp
  SetEnv GEM_HOME /mypath/ruby/gems
</IfModule>
```

and my Sinatra app has two routes

```
get '/' do
  'Root Request'
end

get '/ok' do
  'Ok Request'
end
```

My root route works fine but my second route never gets called. I'm guessing its something between Passenger and Apache configuration but I can't figure it out.

This is running on a shared host so I only have access to my home directory and not the full Apache config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I had to look outside the box.

The problem was in the .htacess file of the parent folder (root of the site) which has a mod_rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

After adding my app folder with the following condition, everything started working as expected:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myapp(.*)$ [NC]
```